# laravel 5.6 on a subdomain Internal Server Error Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

It doesn't write anything to the error logs!

I have a subdomain that points to the IP of the server that hosts the laravel app.

The homepage works fine (subdomain.domain.com) and shows the laravel logo.

Anything else I add to the URL shows this error.

For example: subdomain.domain.com/test shows this error:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, cgiadmin@yourhostingaccount.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I'm using an apache virtualhost to handle the request and it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName subdomain.domain.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/public/

        <Directory /var/www/mysite/public/>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Here's the .htaccess in the public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Both the default error log file and the one I specified in the virtualhost are empty.

When I use the IP directly it works fine.
so http://123.123.123.123/test works.

Comment: Have you set up a route for /test in routes/web.php?

Comment: Yes sir, and if I hadn't the error would be a 404, not this.